# emailing to multiple recipients from asp.net 4.0 website

Tags: asp.net, email

I have built a site which emails users taking addresses from a database when certain conditions arise.
In future the email recipient list may grow rather large and IM wondering is it best to run the query to get the recipients then loop through them sending 1 eamil each, or send 1 email to every recipient at the same time?
ANy thoughts?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course one email to all recipients. Sending every email need some time and gives your mail server lots of work.  If you want them not to see each other emails put e-mail address into BCC (Blind Carbon Copy) field.

Comment: performance-wise, is the 1 mail more efficient then than multiple ones, even with a large BCC list?

Comment: First of all you don't have to store all your emails - less disk space required ie it will be 100 times less if you have 100 recipients per email. And yes it will be performance-wise because when you send an email you have to authenitacate, send a request and wait for response. Lets assume 1 email is like 10ms auth, 20 ms send it, 10 ms store an email. When you send 100 of them you will get 100 *(10 + 20 + 10) but one email is only 10 + 100*20 + 10. Clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

Either one could get you in trouble as far as being identified as a spammer, if other things are not done properly. (those questions are more suited to Serverfault.com, IMO).

But for each individual recipient, in my opinion it's better to send a single e-mail to each person or use the BCC field instead. In particular, you should *never* send a big To/CC list when multiple people in those lists do not already have each others' e-mail addresses - because you are then giving away their private information.

Comment: just a point on your comment RE spamming - all recipients would have sign up on the site, would this still be a potential problem?

Comment: That's a definite must, to keep people from explicitly complaining about the mails. The BCC field will help a lot, because destinations won't see some huge "to/cc" list, which can be a spam flag. But some small amount of "spam" weight is usually given also to emails arriving only due to the BCC. Keep the volume reasonable, and it'll probably be OK.